# How to suppress flask_mail console output

Tags: flask, flask-mail

I'm using flask_mail to connect to send emails through gmail. However, the console is printing out the entire html of the render template and other sends/reply.

How do I suppress this? Can't find any documentation in https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/

```
mail = Mail(app).init_app(app)

def send_confirmation_email(email, token):
    link = url_for('confirm_email', token=token, _external=True)
    with app.app_context():
        msg = Message('Confirm Email', sender=app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"], recipients=[email])
        msg.html = render_template('email_confirmation.html', link=link, type_of_action="email confirmation")
    mail.send(msg)
```

getting:

```
send: 'ehlo 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 35882577\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: b'250 SMTPUTF8\r\n'
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: b'220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: b'2.0.0 Ready to start TLS'
send: 'ehlo 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 35882577\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: b'250 SMTPUTF8\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'smtp.gmail.com at your service, 
reply: b'235 2.7.0 Accepted\r\n'
reply: retcode (235); Msg: b'2.7.0 Accepted'
reply: b'250 2.1.0 OK o23sm683400qtf.53 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.1.0 OK o23sm683400qtf.53 - gsmtp'
reply: b'250 2.1.5 OK o23sm683400qtf.53 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.1.5 OK o23sm683400qtf.53 - gsmtp'
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: b'354  Go ahead o23sm683400qtf.53 - gsmtp\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: b'Go ahead o23sm683400qtf.53 - gsmtp'
data: (354, b'Go ahead o23sm683400qtf.53 - gsmtp')
send: CONTENT TYPE ALL MY HTML FROM RENDER TEMPLATE
```

Comment: Try to set in your configuration  DEBUG = False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually in the documentation.

Set `MAIL_DEBUG = False`

Comment: I must have missed that. Thanks so much!